# Kernel boot problem (initramfs) 14.04

Tags: 14.04, boot, initramfs

I am getting desperate about a boot problem, since ubuntu (14.04) is kicking me to the initramfs prompt. From there I tried several tips I found online without success and the only thing that worked was boot from the previous kernel version.
I cleaned the kernels that were crushing (purged with apt-get, or synaptic, was the same) and updated grub so that I would have only the ones that booted. That way I had a normal machine behavior but I was using the older kernel...
I was hoping that that way I could reinstall the newer kernels and solve the problem completely, but that was not possible. If I install or reinstall any of the newer kernels I get the same boot problem and I think that the problem is that something stays on my machine.
For example I try to look for the kernels installed by

```
 dpkg --list | grep linux-image
```

and I get

```
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-24-generic 3.13.0-24.47                                        amd64 Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-24-generic 3.13.0-24.47                                        amd64 Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-34-generic 3.13.0-34.60                                        amd64 Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-35-generic 3.13.0-35.62                                        amd64 Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
```

even though 34 and 35 are uninstalled

This is shown also from the output if I type:

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-signed-image-3.13.0-{34,35}-generic
```

I get:

```
Package 'linux-signed-image-3.13.0-34-generic' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-signed-image-3.13.0-35-generic' is not installed, so not removed
```

Note that only 24 is booting now and I have to do something, because when one script crashes and I try to reboot, I lose one kernel and now I have only 1 left!!
For sure there must be a way to completely remove the kernel and the corresponding boot info and reinstall completely fresh.

Any ideas? (I would like to avoid fresh install since I have a lot of software which is difficult to compile)